# Create certificate for SHA-3

Tags: windows, ssl, certificate, tomcat8, sha-3

I am trying to create a certificate for **SHA-3**. Which tool can I use to create it?
Currently, I am using SHA-256. Will OpenSSL work in this case? If yes then how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is generally not considered a good idea. The idea of using a certificate is to allow other people to verify the identity of whatever you are serving. SHA-3 is still relatively new and support for legacy devices is a problem. [This Answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/153058/163495) explains more about that in detail.

Further, the post you linked explains how to use a SHA-256 hash for your certificate. SHA-256 belongs to the SHA-2 family, not the SHA-3 family.

Comment: Thanks. The answer you linked helped me. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @priyankacharoliya I am very glad it helped you, although comments should not be used solely to say "Thank you". Upvoting and accepting the answer is the prefered way. Just as a suggestion, I recommend you to take a look at letsencrypt.org to learn how to get a certificate trusted by most browsers.